# can we use regex expression in prefix in terraform replication configuration block

Tags: terraform

I am using s3 module https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-s3-bucket for creating the buckets. I need to add a cross account replication configuration for a bucket and need to exclude a folder **test** in the bucket from getting replicated from source bucket to the destination bucket. The bucket has folders of following format and it continues in the similar way

```
0067hy89-9834-c91c-6it78-d45678as5673
0081as45-1988-e32i-4zx01-l3688we31356
test
0019li23-2012-b41l-7vd38-k267180qw340
```

The condition is that all the above folders should be replicated except the test folder. I could not find any exclude to be used in the prefix to do this. Also, I read that S3 lifecycles rules do not support regular expressions. Can we use regex expression in s3 replication configuration block to use a filter where the prefix should include all the alpha numeric folders mentioned above except the test folder . Please suggest if it is possible to use regex in the replication configuration prefix